# Logstash 2.0: How to drop a failed parse event?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

My logstash config file parses a CSV file that also contains blank lines and other lines that do not match the CSV filter. Logstash generates the following error when encountering a blank line:

"Trouble parsing csv {:source=>"message", "raw"=>"", "exception=>#, :level=>:warn}"

How do I skip a blank or empty line in logstash?  How do I skip events that fail to be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would drop the events that you know are invalid, like blank lines:

```
filter {
    if [message] =~ /^$/ {
        drop { }
    }
}
```

if there are other kinds that you can drop (comment lines that start with "#", etc), do that as well.

You may want to know about the other "unparsable" lines.  If you don't want to put them into your index, consider sending them to a file.  I don't recall if the csv filter indicates success/failure, but you can do it yourself:

```
csv {
    ...
    add_tag => [ "csvOK" ]
}
```

This tag will only be added if the csv filter worked.  Then output those events to a different location:

```
output {
    if "csvOK" in [tags] {
         elasticsearch {
             ...
         }
    }
    else {
         file {
             ...
         }
    }
 }
```

[ NOTE: pseudo-code ]

Comment: That was very helpful.  In logstash <2.0 it seems that the csv filter did add a [_csvparsefailure] tag to indicate failure but it doesn't seem to do that in logstash 2.0.  Also, I found that if I only added the "csvOK" tag on successful csv parsing and did not add the conditional to filter out an empty line, the event was getting sent to the output filter anyway.

Comment: It should still be generating the error tag.  https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-csv/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/csv.rb#L119